# Strange behaviour with .htaccess and CodeIgniter controller URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

The code below in my htaccess always seem to do the trick for me, for any URL in my website.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt|js|files|icons|fonts|extplorer|static|google)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But now I'm getting a strange behaviour where only the index of the controller will work.
So `http://www.website.com/controller` is OK but `http://www.website.com/controller/method` gives me:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /home/interess/public_html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 233
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have custom routing rules setup?

Comment: nope. Only a default_controller.

Comment: what's your `base_url` set to in the config file?

Comment: `http://www.example.org/` - it was all working fine until yesterday. I went in today and this started happening. Already tried a bunch of stuff on htaccess, no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. After almost plucking my eyelids off, found that it was the `$config['csrf_protection']` setting which was causing this most bizarre behaviour.